# There is an empty value given as standard value on my input field, I don't know where it come from

Tags: php, html

I have a weird issue in my PHP which gives an empty value at 1 of my input fields.

You can see that the value has an empty string

[image: image 1]

You definitely can tell It shows an error when there is nothing in that input. There is no space character given

[image: image 4]

Here you see what it sends if I insert a user

[image: image 2]

This is the error that have to appear

[image: image 3]

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Code needs to bne in your question, not images. Can you add the code please?

Comment: Ok ignore me + rules, no need to bother, someone has answered :shrug:

Comment: As Johannes says, you could use empty(trim($_POST['name']))
It looks like your value contains a space " " not "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `trim()` on that value before validating it - it will remove any spaces at the beginning and end of the string, so if the string only consists of one space (or several spaces) originally, it will be empty after applying `trim()` to it and therefore not validate.